# I'm trying to populate data from spreadsheet using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to populate data to a table in Main.html and javascript, but it still empty......[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4BAb.jpg)

This is Main.html

```
<table class = "table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Pembeli</th>
<th>Penjual</th>
<th>No. HP</th>
<th>Harga</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Tanggal</th>
<th>Aksi</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody id = "tableBody-pulsa">

</tbody> 
</table>


</main>

<template id = "rowTemplate">
<tr>
<td class = "template-pembeli"></td>
<td class = "template-penjual"></td>
<td class = "template-nohp"></td>
<td class = "template-harga"></td>
<td class = "template-status"></td>
<td class = "template-tanggal"></td>
<td class = "template-aksi"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square button-edit"></i><i class="bi bi-trash button-hapus"></i></td>
</tr>
</template>
```

This is bacatransaksi.gs

```
function tampilkantransaksi() {

  const dataTransaksi = sheetPulsa.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  dataTransaksi.shift();
  if (dataTransaksi.length === 0 ){
return "Tidak ada transaksi untuk ditampilkan"
  }
  console.log(dataTransaksi);
  return dataTransaksi;
}
```

and this is JS.html

```
function cariData(){
google.script.run
tampilkantransaksi();
.withSuccessHandler(dataTransaksi=>{
let tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody-pulsa");
var template = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
var templateContent = template.content;

dataTransaksi.forEach( pulsa =>{
const tr = templateContent.cloneNode(true);

const pembeliCol = tr.querySelector(".template-pembeli");
const penjualCol = tr.querySelector(".template-penjual");
const nohpCol = tr.querySelector(".template-nohp");
const hargaCol = tr.querySelector(".template-harga");
const statusCol = tr.querySelector(".template-status");
const tanggalCol = tr.querySelector(".template-tanggal");
const editButton = tr.querySelector(".button-edit");
const deleteButton = tr.querySelector(".template-delete");


pembeliCol.textContent = pulsa[1];
penjualCol.textContent = pulsa[2];
nohpCol.textContent = pulsa[3];
hargaCol.textContent = pulsa[4];
statusCol.textContent = pulsa[5];
tanggalCol.textContent = pulsa[6];
editButton.dataset.id = pulsa[0];
deleteButton.dataset.id = pulsa[0];

tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  })
})
.tampilkantransaksi();
}
  </script>
```

it cannot showing table in Main.html, any suggestion how to resolve this? I followed videos on youtube, but, still not resolve problem.
I hope somebody can answer and give solution

Comment: You have `tampilkantransaksi();` in there one too many times

Comment: Your code is not reproducible enough for me.  It would require me to make an effort greater than I wish to make.

Comment: Also you can not pass Dates from server to client.  You need to pass Dates as a string.  [See this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)